# Convenient shell idiom for inverse "use alternative value"

Tags: shell, posix, sh

I'm looking for a quick POSIX shell idiom that does the *inverse* of [`${VARIABLE:+word}` "use alternative value" parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

That is, when VARIABLE is null or unset, I want *word*, but when VARIABLE is not null, I want null.

For example, if I have a shell variable FLAG_VERBOSE, I can easily make normally quiet commands more verbose when that variable is non-null:

```
some_quiet_cmd ${FLAG_VERBOSE:+ --verbose} arg arg arg ... # verbose only if $FLAG_VERBOSE is set
```

However, when I have a normally chatty command, I want to *suppress* its usual chattiness when FLAG_VERBOSE is not set by supplying an argument:

```
if [ "$FLAG_VERBOSE" ]; then
  CHATTINESS=
else
  CHATTINESS=--quiet
fi

some_chatty_cmd $CHATTINESS arg arg arg ... # --quiet unless $FLAG_VERBOSE is set
```

Is there a way to do that in one compact expression?  I feel as though I'm missing a hypothetical parameter expansion operator `${VARIABLE:!word}` or similar.  (Perhaps we'd call this "use complementary value"?)

Comment: Quirky behaviour found while playing with this: `VARIABLE=abc`. Then: `echo "XXX${VARIABLE:+''}YYY"` produces two single quotes: `XXX''YYY`.  However, an assignment without double quotes: `x=${VARIABLE:+''}` followed by `echo "$x"` yields an empty string, but `x="${VARIABLE:+''}"` and `echo "$x"` yields `''` as the output.  There's probably a good explanation somewhere, but it wasn't what I expected.  I got it from both the Heirloom shell and Bash, so it is almost certainly mandated by a standard somewhere.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, interesting!  I'd not have thought that through, but I do think it makes sense in terms of [`sh` quote removal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_07).  I'd expect `VAR=''` and `VAR="''"` to give me empty and just quotes, for instance.

Comment: The right-hand side of an assignment does not undergo word-splitting, but it *does* undergo quote removal. It's easier to see comparing `x=''` and `x="''"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most convenient form I can come up with:

```
some_chatty_cmd $( [ "$FLAG_VERBOSE" ] || echo --quiet ) arg... # default --quiet
#               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: `echo` with a string that starts with a `-` is a bad idea. (Unspecified behaviour per spec I believe). Use `printf`.

Comment: The implementation may interpret a leading - as an argument, and there is no way to suppress this behavior per spec, yes.

Answer (score 2):

the idea of a function is the way to go:

```
~.$ blank_or () { [[ $# -lt 2 ]] && { echo blank_or "\$var" default 1>&2; return 1; }; [[ "$1" = "" ]] && echo $2; }
~.$ this=that; blank_or "$this" --quiet
~.$ this=; blank_or "$this" --quiet
--quiet
~.$ blank_or
blank_or $var default
~.$
```

and, if you intend to use it often, provide a helper.  so your example becomes:

```
some_chatty_cmd $(blank_or "$FLAG_VERBOSE" --quiet) arg arg arg ...
```

Comment: `[[` isn't POSIX _per se_, it's a permitted but unspecified extension to the shell language.

Comment: I agree that a function is a good way to handle it. I have reservations about the function written. If you're going to give it error checking (for a function written in the current file, I wouldn't bother), then the argument count check should either require exactly two arguments or the code should shift argument 1 out of the way and `echo "$@"`. I'd probably use `[ -z "$1" ]` too, but that's mostly style rather than substance.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not possible in shell. You could write a function, or clone the value early.

My own idioms depend on the behaviour of the callee a lot. If you have `--verbose` and `--quiet` GNU tools, I’d just assign them to two variables:

```
if test -n "$FLAG_VERBOSE"; then
    v=--verbose
    q=
else
    v=
    q=--quiet
fi
```

Then I just add `$v` and `$q` as necessary.

Comment: I know it's not possible in `sh`. Give me your best idiomatic equivalent :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if [ -n "$FLAG_VERBOSE" ]; then CHATTINESS=; else CHATTINESS=--quiet; fi

some_chatty_cmd $CHATTINESS ${FLAG_VERBOSE:+ --verbose} arg arg arg
```

Comment: This looks substantively equivalent to @mirabilos' [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27602197/132382)

Comment: It is actually the same as the example code in the OP itself.